# How does WordPress Multisite know that a Plugin is installed?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I am running a WP Multisite Network.

I am curious to know how WordPress knows that a plugin is installed on a network site:

- how does WP know that a plugin is Network Activated?
- how does WP know that a plugin is activated at the site level?

Does it record this instance in a DB Table somewhere? If so, which table and how is it tagged?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clearly see the way WordPress loads plugins if you inspect the source code of the file `wp-settings.php`.

The function `wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()` loads plugins for individual sites in the network and for non-Multi-Site installations, while `wp_get_active_network_plugins()` loads network activated plugins when Multi-Site is enabled.

The former more or less just calls [get_option()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to get the `active_plugins` option from the wp_options database table, while the latter uses [get_site_option()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_option) which is the network-wide version of `get_option()`. The option which has the network enabled plugins is called `active_sitewide_plugins`.

Comment: As hint, the plugin [Multisite Enhancements](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-enhancements/) give you an overview about all plugins, themes and in which blog or network is it active. Maybe this helps you fast.